# Is variable substitution $x-h=a$ appropriate under limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Originally, I have $$ \lim_{h\to 0}(f(x+h)-f(x-h))=0$$ If I let $x-h=a$, will I get $$\lim_{h\to 0}(f(a+2h)-f(a))=0\quad ?$$ I feel confused because $a$ is related to $h$ somehow, but doing this substitution makes the second term irrelevant to $h$, and then I can take $f(a)$ out of the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, $x$ is fixed, and $h$ is variable.

If you let $a=x-h$, then $a$ is a variable dependent on $h$. So you can't take it out of the limit; it is not constant. There is nothing you can do with the second limit that you couldn't do with the first.

Answer (score 0):

From the first limit we see that $h$ is varying and $x$ is constant.
So if you consider the change of variable for h, $a=x-h$, then your new variable is $a$, and as $h$ approach $0$, $a$ must approach $x$. Thus your limit must  become $$ \lim_{a \rightarrow x} (f(2x+a)-f(a))=0 .$$